# Error when bootstrapping CMake:Log of errors

Tags: linux, cmake

To install charmm program I have to install CMake, however, it doesn't install CMake.

```
[sohyeon@theochem11 cmake-3.15.3]$ ./bootstrap 
---------------------------------------------
CMake 3.15.3, Copyright 2000-2019 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
Found GNU toolchain
C compiler on this system is: gcc       
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Cannot find a C++ compiler that supports both C++11 and the specified C++ flags.
Please specify one using environment variable CXX.
The C++ flags are "".
They can be changed using the environment variable CXXFLAGS.
See cmake_bootstrap.log for compilers attempted.
---------------------------------------------
Log of errors: /export/home/sohyeon/cmake-3.15.3/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log
```

so I tried to that script

```
[sohyeon@theochem11 cmake-3.15.3]$ env CC=cc CXX=CC ./bootstrap
```

But it still occurred same error.

I searched other ways in google. I found this two ways.

```
$ yum -y install gcc-c++ 
You need to be root to perform this command.

$ yum install gcc-c++.x86_64 
You need to be root to perform this command.
```

But it is not solve my problem.

(And I saw cmake_bootstrap.log but I don't know what is wrong.)

---

(Edit)
Thank you all!

OS version : Linux theochem11.hpc.org 2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 6 23:43:09 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[sohyeon@theochem11 cmake-3.15.3]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[sohyeon@theochem11 cmake-3.15.3]$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: Ask your system administrator which development tools (cmake and clang/g++ at least) are installed (if any) and how you can bring them in scope. Perhaps it is as simple as updating your `$PATH` variable somehow.

Comment: »» Cannot find a C++ compiler that supports both C++11 and the specified C++ flags «« : Please edit your question to include OS name and version, gcc/g++ version. Then you will get information about a gcc version that can build Cmake.

Answer (score 5):

`cmake-3.15.3` can do bootstrap with g++ versions 6.3 .. 9.2 . ... Earlier g++ versions like 4.9 or 5.3 are failing.

---

RHEL 6, install gcc-c++-7.3 :

```
# 1. Install a package with repository for your system:
# On CentOS, install package centos-release-scl available in CentOS repository:
$ sudo yum install centos-release-scl

# On RHEL, enable RHSCL repository for you system:
$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms

# 2. Install the collection:
$ sudo yum install devtoolset-7

# 3. Start using software collections:
$ scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
```

https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/

Five packages only are installed, with 'yum install devtoolset-7-gcc-c++' :

```
devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.3.1-5.15.el6.x86_64
devtoolset-7-binutils-2.28-11.el6.x86_64
devtoolset-7-libstdc++-devel-7.3.1-5.15.el6.x86_64
devtoolset-7-runtime-7.1-4.el6.x86_64
devtoolset-7-gcc-7.3.1-5.15.el6.x86_64
```

Packages http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/x86_64/rh/devtoolset-7/

---

Cmake :

```
cd cmake-3.15.3/
scl enable devtoolset-7 bash     // g++ is set to "7.3"
./bootstrap
```

Note : The command `scl enable devtoolset-7 bash` is valid for the current terminal session only.

---

P.S. : cmake3 is available from the EPEL repo https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL → `sudo yum install cmake3` . You get cmake3-3.6.1-3.el6.x86_64 . Provides `/usr/bin/cmake3`

Epel packages https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/Packages/

---

Ref. comment

> Is there any other way than using yum?

The rpm command can be used to install downloaded packages : Root password is required. Examples ...

```
rpm -Uvh cmake3-3.6.1-3.el6.x86_64

rpm -Uvh <package>.rpm <package>.rpm  <package>.rpm <package>.rpm <package>.rpm
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your commend so I write code my linux terminal, but it doesn't work.                                                                              '[sohyeon@theochem11 ~]$ yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-6-rpms   /   
You must be root to change the yum configuration.'                                                        Is this sentence meaning that my linux system not install yum?

Comment: To use `yum` the root password must be entered. .... I case you have no Redhat subscription, the mentioned packages can be installed with `yum install [package].rpm` ... also as root.

Comment: Is there any other way than using yum?

Comment: Installing downloaded packages : See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problems,you can solve it by downloading the latest version

Comment: Latest version of what?